# compile program with non-default glibc

Tags: compilation, glibc

i've tried compiling the cuda sdk kit on my computer, but it failed, saying that it required glibc 2.7.

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so: undefined reference to 
`__isoc99_sscanf@GLIBC_2.7'
```

so i went ahead, and installed glibc-2.7; but in /mydir/glibc-2.7. the installation ended without any errors.

however, i want to be able to link the cuda sdk kit with my glibc. i've tried

```
export PATH=/mydir/glibc-2.7/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mydir/glibc-2.7/lib
```

but all i get is segmentation fault =)

i'd appreciate any help !
thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-6.html) for more instructions regarding compiling with a non-primary or custom libc.

In summary in addition to your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH you need to set custom CFLAGS and LDFLAGS with -nostdinc , and -I includedirectories and -b gccsetup .